# Piano notes data set for machine learning?

Tags: python, python-3.x, machine-learning

I'm looking to do a research project on generating piano notes and I'm wondering if anyone knows of any good datasets that have full songs with just notes (no audio needed)?

So for example, the dataset might have something like this:

```
Song Name,  notes

song_1   ,  Eb C Fbb        #I don't play piano as you can tell
```

I understand there is Magenta's dataset but as far as I can see it is more focused on the audio end of things and not just the notes (if I'm correct?).

appreciate any help or suggestions.

Comment: I guess you are looking for MIDI (Musical Instrument Digital Interface)  file formats which is:A standard protocol for the interchange of musical information between musical instruments, synthesizers and computers

Answer (score 0):

I think this is the closest you can get: https://github.com/wayne391/symbolic-musical-datasets

Some other useful datasets/generators:

https://github.com/craffel/pretty-midi

https://research.google.com/audioset/dataset/piano.html

https://magenta.tensorflow.org/datasets/maestro

You can analyze raw piano audio and do frequency analysis to find the notes (will be slightly challenging though).